# get value of element of html in another js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my index page i sent a request ajax and response is a number.and i set the response to the value of input with hidden type

```
<input type="hidden" id="Status">
<script src="js/indexPhone.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#SendPhone").click(function(e) {
        var phoneField = $("#PhoneField").val();
        var phoneFieldString = "989" + phoneField.substring(0);
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'getSMS.php',
            data:{'phoneFieldString':phoneFieldString},
            success:(function (response) {
                $("#Status").val(response);
            })
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

and my problem is i want to get this value in another javascript page that i included in my index but it alerts empty. this my indexPhone.js:

```
$("#SendPhone").click(function() {
    alert($("#Status").val());
});
```

Comment: wrap it in document,ready in your another js file

Comment: Is it in iframe?

Comment: So you're adding listener for click event to one element twice? I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve. Maybe you don't need `$("#SendPhone").click(function(e){ })` for your ajax request?

Comment: @Walk so what i have to do?i want it in ajax because i want when clicked ajax sends

Comment: once you are setting the value to #Status, try to get the value immediately after the ajax  call,If it works, it should work in another js file of same page..

Comment: I'm still not sure what exactly is your goal. Do you want to send this request once and then alert received value on next clicks? Or do you want to send this request each time your element is clicked? It's empty at first because `ajax` is asynchronous, so you're calling `alert` before you get response.

Comment: @Walk i want send ajax request and set its response to input value and alert the input value in js file in same one click. please help i'm confused

Comment: @sepehr Did you see my answer?

Comment: @aaron yeah its result is ok.but where i have to write in my indexPhone.js??

Comment: @sepehr Replace your current statement. Please continue discussion on my answer.

Comment: @aaron i must have the function in my indexPhone.js because i have a lot codes after that here i didn't write

Comment: @sepehr Continue discussion on my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Ajax request is asynchronous, so the second click runs before value is set.

Use events:

```
// index.html
$("#SendPhone").click(function (e) {
    // ...
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: (function (response) {
            $("#Status").val(response);
            $("#Status").trigger("gotSMS");
        })
    });
});

// indexPhone.js
$("#Status").on("gotSMS", function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```